# Active MQ Consumer stops receiving messages after several restarts. Need to restart Active MQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue (Active MQ). I have a producer that sends messages to queue, and I have a consumer that reads messages from queue. Consumer delegates processing of a message to a new thread, and processes another message.

My consumer implements javax.jms.MessageListener and its onMessage() method.

Its a Spring application. 
applicationContext.xml for the consumer contains the following:

```
<!-- ActiveMQ broker -->
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="${jms.brokerURL}" />

<!-- JMS Consumer Configuration -->
<bean id="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory"/>


<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
                        connection-factory="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
                        acknowledge="client">
    <jms:listener destination="myQueue" ref="myConsumer" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Also, my consumer bean has init() method (using @PostConstruct annotation), that writes some messages to the queue using @Autowired producer service at startup.

It all works ok. But when I restart the consumer several times, it stops receiving any messages. Active MQ console shows messages as pending.
Restarting Active MQ solves the problem, and consumer receives all the pending messages.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks